# Recursive Partial<T> in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```
export interface UserSettings
{
    one: {
        three: number;
        four: number;
    };
    two: {
        five: number;
        six: number;
    };
}
```

...and want to turn it into this:

```
export interface UserSettingsForUpdate
{
    one?: {
        three?: number;
        four?: number;
    };
    two?: {
        five?: number;
        six?: number;
    };
}
```

...but `Partial<UserSettings>` produces this:

```
{
    one?: {
        three: number;
        four: number;
    };
    two?: {
        five: number;
        six: number;
    };
}
```

Is it possible to use mapped types to make all the properties on all depths optional, or do I have to create an interface manually for that?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

With the landing of Conditional Types in 2.8, we can now declare a recursive partial type as follows.

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?:
    T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
    T[P] extends object | undefined ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
    T[P];
};
```

Reference:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

Comment: This is great. It would be very nice if this declaration shipped with typescript in lib.d.ts.

Comment: Just a note, the second condition was too restrictive for me, where some types that must not match the `object` type where requiring all properties to be filled out instead of partially. I simplified it to `T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] : RecursivePartial<T[P]>`

Comment: This won’t work if any of the properties are already optional. Replace `T[P] extends object` with `T[P] extends (object | undefined)` to fix.

Comment: This broke for me after upgrading to typescript 3.8.2 for sub objects with the type `interface Foo { readonly [id: string]: ReadonlyArray<Bar>; }` with the error `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'readonly Bar[]'.`

Comment: This type lead to a difficult-to-trace situation where `tsc` would run for 30 minutes and eventually gave an out of memory error. The answer with `tsdef` below did work however.

Comment: This works fine until you have a type like `NodeJS.ReadStream` (or `WriteStream`), which gives the error `Property '[Symbol.asyncIterator]' is missing in type 'RecursivePartial<ReadStream>' but required in type 'ReadStream'.` - I ended up using the [tsdef](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56403542/8602926) package, which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: The `object` type is flagged by eslint, so I used this instead:
`type RecursivePartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?:
      T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? RecursivePartial<U>[] :
      T[P] extends (number | string | symbol | undefined) ? T[P] : RecursivePartial<T[P]>;
  };`

Comment: Why is it necessary to add the `T[P] extends object ? RecursivePartial<T[P]> :
    T[P];` ? Isn't it enough to just use `RecursivePartial<T[P]>` directly?

Comment: To fix the issue with types that are already optional it's interesting to use the TypeScript's native NonNullable type. `[P in keyof NonNullable<T>]`, `NonNullable<T[P]> extends (infer U)[]`, `NonNullable<T[P]> extends object`.

Answer (score 45):

you could make your own mapping type, like this:

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[P]>;
};
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this does not work for array-typed fields. <strike>There does not seem to be a way to do conditional type mapping yet either; i.e. limit to primitives.</strike> See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12114#issuecomment-259776847 Its possible now, see other answer.

Comment: Nice, thanks! However, if I change the `Bar` interface to `interface Bar { names: string[]; }` then VS Code tells me that `names` has the type `RecursivePartial` instead of `string[]`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I suspect this is a current limitation: see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12114#issuecomment-259776847, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13257

Comment: I'll watch those issues and update this answer when they are resolved.

Answer (score 20):

I've made a library, [tsdef](https://github.com/joonhocho/tsdef) that has many common patterns / snippets like this.

For this case, you can use it like the following:

```js
import { DeepPartial } from 'tsdef';

let o: DeepPartial<{a: number}> = {};
```

Comment: Very nice library, with a lot of examples to learn from. Source is here https://github.com/joonhocho/tsdef/blob/master/src/index.ts

Answer (score 9):

Neither of the provided solutions is good enough. Here is an explanation:

```
const x: RecursivePartial<{dateValue: Date}> = {dateValue: 0}; // ja-ja-ja
```

In the code above the actual type of the `dateValue` is `RecursivePartial<Date> | undefined` which allows to assign any value!!!
Expected type of the `dateValue` is just `Date`, however the rule `T[P] extends object ? RecursivePartial<T[P]>` is too broad.

The solution is to separate primitives and eliminate `extends object`:

```
export type RecursivePartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?:
    T[P] extends Array<infer U> ? Array<Value<U>> : Value<T[P]>;
};
type AllowedPrimitives = boolean | string | number | Date /* add any types than should be considered as a value, say, DateTimeOffset */;
type Value<T> = T extends AllowedPrimitives ? T : RecursivePartial<T>;
```

Comment: Why does RecursivePartial<Date> allow any value???

Comment: Because the rule `T[P] extends object` is to broad.

Comment: But then why is it not too broad for `RegExp` or normal objects?

Comment: I would add Function to AllowedPrimitives as well

Comment: Actually, the final sulution is obviously depends on your needs. Say, if one has classes which are considered as primitives, such as DateTimeOffset or Longitude, these should be included into the AllowedPrimitives list

Answer (score 2):

thanks to @jefferey-peterson and @pavel-husakouski, my implementation is similar by ignoring primitive types and it's array as is with fallback to recursive partial.

```js
/** ADD YOUR OWN SELECTION OF PRIMITIVES **/
type Primitives =
  | boolean
  | number
  | bigint
  | string
  | symbol
  | void
  | null
  | undefined
  | Date
  | Buffer
  | Function
  | RegExp;
 
type RecursivePartial<T> = T extends Primitives
  ? T /** RESOLVE PRIMITIVE TO ITSELF */
  : T extends Array<infer U>
  ? Array<RecursivePartial<U>> /** RESOLVE ARRAY */
  : T extends Map<infer K, infer V>
  ? Map<RecursivePartial<K>, RecursivePartial<V>> /** RESOLVE MAP */
  : T extends WeakMap<infer K, infer V>
  ? WeakMap<RecursivePartial<K>, RecursivePartial<V>> /** RESOLVE WEAK-MAP */
  : T extends Set<infer V>
  ? Set<RecursivePartial<V>> /** RESOLVE SET */
  : T extends WeakSet<infer V>
  ? WeakSet<RecursivePartial<V>> /** RESOLVE WEAK-SET */
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[K]> /** RESOLVES OBJECT */;
    }
  : T; /** FALLBACK TO ITSELF IF NOT HANDLED */
```