# Recursive partial with depth

Tags: typescript

In typescript we already have ability to use recursive partial: [Recursive Partial<T> in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980195/recursive-partialt-in-typescript)

Is it possible to create the same generic but with ability to set `depth` level for it?

For example:

```
interface RecursivePartialWithDepth<T, Depth extends number = 0> {
  ...implementation
}
```

So that we can use it for arbitrary level of depth:

```
type p1 = {
  a: number;
};

type p2 = {
  b: p1;
  c: number;
};

type p3 = {
  d: p2;
  e: number;
};

type PartialWithLevelTwo = RecursivePartialWithDepth<p3, 2>;

/* and it will result to:
    { d?: { b?: { a: number }, c?: number }, e?: number }
    
    Note that `a` is required!
*/
```

And if it is possible, then how to create such a Generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
type Increment<A extends number[]> = [...A, 0];

type DeepPartial<
  T,
  Depth extends number = 0,
  CurrentDepth extends number[] = []
> = T extends PrimitiveType
  ? T
  : CurrentDepth["length"] extends Depth
  ? T
  : {
      [K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[K], Depth, Increment<CurrentDepth>>;
    };

type PartialWithLevelTwo = DeepPartial<p3, 2>;
const partialItem: PartialWithLevelTwo = {};

type PrimitiveType =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | undefined
  | null
  | symbol
  | bigint;
```

Explanation:

We first define a utility type `Increment` that increments the length of the provided tuple.

Then we define `DeepPartial`; it takes `T`, the type to operate on, `Depth`, the desired depth (by default it is 0), and `CurrentDepth`, the current depth we are at.

If `T` extends a primitive, we just return `T`.

However, if it isn't it must be an object of some sort.

If the current depth we are at exceeds the depth limit, we stop and return `T`.

If we can still go on, we do what `Partial` does.

The only thing different is that instead of `T[K]` we use `DeepPartial` again, provide the same depth, and increment the current depth.

A fair note: because this expects `number[]` as the depth (using the length of the array as our number here), you must provide `[0, 0]` if you want a depth of `2` etc.

You can however, write a type that can create an array of length N filled with 0's.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

[Here's a version that uses numbers instead of arrays but is limited by Increment's range](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgYwE4QLYTsAPAQShAD2AwBMBnKOAV1QCMIkA+KAXigG0BGAGigCZeAZl4AWXgFZeANl4B2XgA5eATl6cADLwD0AKigA6Q1B1aAuuxymA3AFgAUPdCQoAEQgQwABQCGSYAEtvABssABVeNzBgAAt8IlIKajoGVkoaeiReAGEqJBRMSJi44jhyNOSkVPVmFnsoeqhQ4oSoMmAkfzgAcygAH3KMvqhaAHsRoIhvOCHafy7O4CGyEDpxoeogoKGqUogAM06IEjqG04B+RpPT+oAuKBy8jGBC2MISsper6-PLu2-vu4Aby+-2u7AA0lBOlAANYQEAjPaNUxnO5uDw+PyBEKhCGmCIeGK8eDINBPLAPfLPQnRRiMWx-UENAC+DMc4GgYE4qWBjO8dySGQZrPs7OcYD4PJOtCBX35AwYDPqIsZCAF6UV9hVYs5giljJIssZ9RlUF533lgs1xqgKtOaoVSCVtudEHVFWFbLsTmgmICwQA6v4YgAZCAANwgQVCAHcRql0V5fP6QmBhPx6fYtFoGgA9M5AA)

Comment: Will it work with arrays? I just think, that we should add one more `extend` to Generic to handle arrays.